# Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 in ASP.NET MVC 5

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have problem with my MVC project, I'm trying to send a call using Ajax
It send successfully and it go to the server and get data but never success in AJAK Method

This code:

```
function getSpeTemplate() {

    var tempId = $('#ddlTemplates :selected').val();

    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        //data: JSON.stringify(data),
        url: '/WhatsMessage/GetTemplate?idx=' + tempId,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {

            alert("Success Okay");    //  This alert never popup

            if (data !== null) {

                
                $('#rowTemplateData').css("display", "block");
                                    
                $('#templateNameSend').html(data.TemplateName);

            }
        },
        fail: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert('request failed');     //  This alert never popup
        }
    });
}
```

This statement never execute:   alert("Success Okay")

And also fail alert never execute: alert('request failed');

Comment: I think, and it has been a while since JQuery, you want 'error' not 'fail' for your error handler when using the settings like that. You are probably missing the error response as a result.

Comment: Yes, you are right, I used 'error' and get the reason and fix it,  Thank you